# npm ERR! Failed at the react-complete-guide@0.1.0 start script

Tags: reactjs

Hello I had installed create-react-app

Now when I try to `npm` start in my app I got the following error. Any idea about how to solve this issue?

Thanks.

`$ npm start`

> react-complete-guide@0.1.0 start C:\Users\clebe\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\projects\react-complete-guide
>   react-scripts start
>
> 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
>   errno 1 npm ERR! react-complete-guide@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts
>   start` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   react-complete-guide@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not
>   a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: pm ERR!
>   C:\Users\clebe\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-04-03T08_48_44_624Z-debug.log

```
$ node --version
v10.15.3

$ webpack --version
4.29.6
```

Comment: can you post your package.json ?